# migrating third party managed and unmanaged package from sandbox to production

Tags: managed-package, deployment, migration, unmanaged-package

we installed some third party managed and unmanaged packages in dev sandbox. we need to move from sandbox to production. what is the recommended way to migrate managed and unmanaged packages from sandbox to production.

Comment: they are third party packages correct ?

Comment: yes third party for stuff like logging errors in a custom debug object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use packages for migrating changes from sandbox to production!

- Managed packages are for publishing commercial applications. They are upgradeable, but they can only be created from a Developer Edition organization, not from a Sandbox. so you need to install that separately on your PROD again.
- Unmanaged packages are NOT upgradeable.  Once you install a component into your production organization using a package, you can change it in your organization but you cannot install another unmanaged package with a newer version of that component into your production organization (unless you uninstall the original package, deleting any data in its schema in the process).

Instead, use the Deploy to Server wizard in Force.com IDE (for Eclipse), or write a script for the Force.com Migration Tool (for Ant), You can also opt changeset to migrate the changes.

Here's a great post on deployment best practices in the Force.com IDE:
http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster (link)

Comment: i made some edits to the question. i want to know what is the right way to have third party managed and unmanaged packaged we installed in our dev sandbox migrated to prod.

Comment: @Walker As I said earlier managed package can't be migrated from sandbox. They can be installed only the way you installed in sandbox. Though you can move unmanaged package components using any above method i.e. Changset, eclipse IDE, force.com migration tool

Comment: ok, so for unmanaged package i will have to specify components of unmanaged package like specific metadata types like apex class, custom object etc while retrieving. and when i deploy components of unmanaged package, will my unmanaged package get installed automatically ? Do i need to specify anything in package.xml for retrieving or deploying for metadata type                                              <types><name>InstalledPackage</name> </types> ?

Comment: yes you need to specify each and every component manually the way you do with rest of the component developed by you and they will be deployed as regular component there is no such thing where it will show as unmanaged package in  your PROD org. makes sense?